# Javascript VAR and HREF

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have in my donation form the amount that the person wishes to donate:

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="<?php echo $minimum_donation; ?>"
 max="100" onchange="changeDonation()">
```

Below that, I have the actual donate button:

```
<a href="<?php echo $paypal_redirect;?>" 
onclick="location.href=this.href+donation;return false;">
```

To make it work, I have this javascript in header:

```
function changeDonation()
{
var donation = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
}
```

How can I make this work??

Comment: You need to describe to us an actual problem you are having.  We don't know what you mean by "how can I make this work", there is simply not enough information here.

Comment: `this.href+donation` could be causing a problem depending on the value of `$paypal_redirect`.  Your value would likely need to be something like `paypal.com/foo?donation=` so when you append the value of donation, it's appended to a Get URL variable (unless Paypal is using some kind of RESTful format then it needs to be configured per their specs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `changeDonation()`, the `donation` variable is local.  Meaning, it only exists inside that function.

I suggest having that function return the donation, instead of trying to update a variable.

```
function changeDonation(){
    return document.getElementById("quantity").value;
}
```

The change your HTML;

```
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="<?php echo $minimum_donation; ?>" max="100" />
<a href="<?php echo $paypal_redirect;?>" onclick="location.href=this.href+changeDonation();return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply submitting the donation value to another page you don't need JavaScript:

```
<form action='<?php echo $paypal_redirect;?>' method='post'>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" min="<?php echo $minimum_donation; ?>" max="100">
    <button type='submit'>Donate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: i can see this would work but my website is really mseed up lol